# Motionevent Action_MOVE keeps firing X and Y even if not moved

Tags: android, motionevent

I am trying out simple program that have sounds based if moved. so at the beginning I have down - which play sound 1 and from then every move it is keeps playing a sound. At count 4 I have made it to play from start.

here is the problem: When I don't move my finger and hold it in the same place the sound still keeps 1 by 1 - Figured out the x and y value firing. How do I stop this??

```
OnTouchListener MyOnTouchListener= new OnTouchListener()
{
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
    {
    switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           x = (int) event.getX();
            y = (int) event.getY();    
            oldval = x+y;
            break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
          Log.e("X value", "X is "+x);
          Log.e("Y value", "Y is "+y);
        try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            int newval= (int) (event.getX() + event.getY()); 

            if(Math.abs(oldval-newval)>50)
            {

                Log.e("First", "next button");
                longpressCount++;
                if(longpressCount==1)
                {
                   Log.e("1", "BUTTON PRESSED");
                }
                else if(longpressCount==2)
                {
                    Log.e("2", "BUTTON PRESSED");
                }
                else if(longpressCount==3)
                {
                    Log.e("3", "BUTTON PRESSED");
                }
                else if(longpressCount==4)
                {
                    Log.e("4", "BUTTON PRESSED");
                    longpressCount = 0;
                }

            }

            break;
         }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MOVE is very sensitive and will continue to be called as long as your finger is down.  Set Old Value at the end of the sound playing code so it will only play if moved another 50 distance from that spot.

Something like this.

```
OnTouchListener MyOnTouchListener= new OnTouchListener()
{
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event)
    {
    switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {

         case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           x = (int) event.getX();
            y = (int) event.getY();    
            oldval = x+y;
            break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        {
          Log.e("X value", "X is "+x);
          Log.e("Y value", "Y is "+y);
        try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            int newval= (int) (event.getX() + event.getY()); 

            if(Math.abs(oldval-newval)>50)
            {

                Log.e("First", "next button");
                longpressCount++;
                if(longpressCount==1)
                {
                   Log.e("1", "BUTTON PRESSED");
                }
                else if(longpressCount==2)
                {
                    Log.e("2", "BUTTON PRESSED");
                }
                else if(longpressCount==3)
                {
                    Log.e("3", "BUTTON PRESSED");
                }
                else if(longpressCount==4)
                {
                    Log.e("4", "BUTTON PRESSED");
                    longpressCount = 0;
                }
                oldval = event.getX() + event.getY();
            }

            break;
         }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Ty S but how do I set the old value? Are you talking about the old value of X and Y from action down?

Comment: Thanks Ty. S. This works - Just figured out using my logic above if any value > 50 works but the problem is that when I scroll from top to bottom - the sound are all played - instead just playing the one sound. The count adds 1 all the time - hence the sound comes up? what do you think would be an issue here?

Comment: you'd probably want to nix using the counter and instead check the distance you expect.  ie. 

if(
diff >200){ do x; }else if(diff > 150){ do y; }else if(diff > 100){ do z; }else if(diff > 50){ do z1;}