# Android - ACTION_UP not detected

Tags: java, android

I am unable to figure out why the ACTION_UP event is not being fired when I move my finger away from contact in the following code.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getActionIndex()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Utils.log("Touch Up");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Utils.log("Touch Down");
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: `switch (event.getAction())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`getActionMasked()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getActionMasked%28%29).

- `getAction()` returns *single* pointer events (and deprecated multiple pointer events...)
- `getActionMasked()` returns *single* and *multiple* pointer events (use with `getActionIndex()` to determine which pointer),
- `getActionIndex()` returns only the pointer index.

So `getActionIndex()` returns which finger performed a down / up action (0, 1, 2, etc.) While `getAction()` or `getActionMasked()` return the *single* pointer events you want (`ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_UP`, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with mine.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          //Here's the problem            
       switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Utils.log("Touch Up");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Utils.log("Touch Down");
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For others having a similar problem, one of the reasons why ACTION_UP is not fired could be overly sensitive ACTION_MOVE. In this case, ACTION_UP never gets fired because system interprets touch action as ACTION_MOVE and fires it instead.

A solution for that is to check when ACTION_MOVE happens if x and y offset is big enough to handle it as ACTION_MOVE, otherwise, you can threat it as ACTION_UP. 
[Here is SO example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328867/motionevent-action-move-keeps-firing-x-and-y-even-if-not-moved)